# How angularjs filters work, does the filter is called in every digest?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

**My supposition about how angularjs filter work:**

**1. Filter is called when the input(or it's child properties) is changed:**

*Example:*

```
{{input | myFilter}}
```

*`myFilter` will be executed when `$scope.input` is changed.*

**2. Filter is called when there is something change in the $scope watcher**

*Example:*

```
{{input | myFilter}}
```

*`myFilter` will be executed when `$scope.input` is changed. And when another `$scope.input2` is changed, the filter will be executed also*

---

**I decided to write a demo to make sure my supposition  is correct:**

*I wrote a `helloWorld` filter. In this filter, It will receive an **Object**(which contain my English name) and **return a string**(which is my Vietnamese name). 
Everytime the filter is called, I will **update the updateIn in the input Object***

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('myReverseFilterApp', [])
  .filter('helloWorld', function() {
    return function(input, uppercase) {
      //Note that input is an object
      var vietnameseName = input.name+ " Nguyen";
      input.vietnameseName = vietnameseName;
      input.updateIn = new Date();
      return vietnameseName;
    };
  })
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.person  = {
      name : "John",
      wife: {
        name: "Bella" ,
        vietnameseName: ""
      },
      vietnameseName: ""
    };
    
    $scope.strange = {
      name: "Anonymous"
    };
    $scope.watched = [];
    $scope.$watch("person.vietnameseName", function(newValue,oldValue){
       $scope.watched.push(new Date());
      
    });
    
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example30-production</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  

   
</head>
<body ng-app="myReverseFilterApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
  My name: <input ng-model="person.name" type="text"><br>
  My wife's name: <input ng-model="person.wife.name" type="text"><br>
  Someone else's name: <input ng-model="strange.name" type="text"><br>
  
  *My name in Vietnamese: {{person|helloWorld}}<br>
  Update in :{{person.updateIn}}<br />
  *My wife's name in Vietnamese: {{person.wife|helloWorld}}<br>
  Update in :{{person.wife.updateIn}}<br />
  <br />
  Watch for `person.vietnameseName`: <br/>
  {{watched}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is my test cases:**

1. update `$scope.person.name`

   - The `$scope.person.updateIn` is changed
   - The `$scope.person.wife.updateIn` is changed as well.

   => My **supposition 1 is wrong**. Because `$scope.person.wife.updateIn` is changed when I change `$scope.person.name` (It should change `$scope.person.updateIn` only)
2. update `$scope.strange.name`

   - The `$scope.person.updateIn` is changed
   - The `$scope.person.wife.updateIn` is changed as well.

   => My **supposition 2 is right**. Filter is called when there is something changed

So : **Filter is called when there is something changed**

There is a problem here: Because I change `$scope.person.vietnameseName` in the filter. => It may cause a loop :

*Call filter => update `$scope.person.vietnameseName` => Call filter => ..and keep going*

But, Actually There is no loop here .

Finally, My question is: **How angularjs filters actually work?**

Comment: have you read the source code?

Comment: @CallumLinington  I'm debugging and reading the AngularJs source code(It will take time ^^).  I think this is an interesting issue (not actually an issue) , so I want to share my problem here :D